# combine consecutive rows if they are matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to combine rows into a single row if the data is consecutive. I've looked over gaps and islands and I know I used to do this very regularly with SQL Server. The solution escapes me, but I recall doing some type of `ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition BY groupId, name, email, phone ORDER BY id) - ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY id) seq` with a calculation. I was not successful in getting this to work.

Here is a sample data set:

[image: data set]

Desired Result:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the last row in each group, you can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(id) over (order by id) as next_id,
             lead(id) over (partition by groupid, name, email, phone order by id) as next_id_grp
      from t
     ) t
where next_id_grp is null or next_id_grp <> next_id;
```

This is looking at the next `id` and the next `id` for members in the same group.  When these are different, then the row is the last row in the group.

This is better than the `row_number()` approach because that would typically require an aggregation.

Comment: This looks like it could work. The question I have is why would lead(id) not be lead(groupId)? My table doesn't have all the group id's in order like the example, I apologize for being shortsighted there

Comment: @vizon . . . No.  This is specifically the unique, ordered identifier for each row.  The `groupid` is part of the `partition by`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I ran the following. It condensed many rows in a table with ~2 million records, but still had thousands of exact subsequent duplicates. Here was my code:
`select null, groupId, name, email, phone
from (
 select  id, groupId, name, email, phone
             lead(id) over (order by groupId, id) as next_id,
             lead(id) over (partition by groupId, name, email, phone order by groupId, id) as next_id_grp
      from t
) t
where next_id_grp is null or next_id_grp != next_id;`

Comment: @Vizon . . . My guess is that the "exact subsequent duplicates" are not really exact.  The names, for instance, might differ by spaces or other hidden characters.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t FSR
INNER JOIN t FSR2 on FSR.id = FSR2.id + 1 AND FSR.groupId = FSR2.groupId AND FSR.name = FSR2.name AND FSR.email = FSR2.email and FSR.phone = FSR2.phone` to get the exact duplicates back, I used the following query. I have to be missing something here.

Comment: I looked through the id's subquery and understood how this solution works! Thank you for your help @Gordon Linoff, the issue was an ordering issue in the select statement.

Comment: do you have a similar solution if we want to keep the first row instead of the last row?